# Get a list of outlook PST in remote computer, C#

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, wmi

I need to get a list of outlook personal folder files `(PST's)` for a user which is  currently logged in on a remote machine.

I tried using `Win32_DataFile` (using WMI Creator from Microsoft), without any success. A search over the Internet always gave me CLOSE results, but not what i wanted. I tried to go to Microsoft website and check the documentation on Inter-op Assembly : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb652780.

I am connecting to remote machine using `WMI` or Registry (both are possible methods).

Can you please help me ?

Thanks !!